# Understanding TypeScript import, module and namespace

Tags: typescript, import, module, namespaces

I'm having trouble trying to import types in my TypeScript project. I'm not entirely sure how import works...

**File *foo.ts***

```
module Foo {
    export class Bar {
    }
}
```

**File *bar.ts***

```
import { Bar } from "Foo";
```

> Cannot find module 'Foo'.

```
import { Bar } from "../scripts/Foo";
```

> File '/scripts/foo.ts' is not a module.

So, what am I misunderstanding here? Also, should I be using `module` or `namespace`, and what is the difference?

**Note** `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` are in the same location...can I omit `../scripts/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are missing is that TypeScript supports two types of modules - [external](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [internal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html). Internal modules were renamed to namespaces in newer versions (that's the reason there is older `module` and newer `namespace` keywords - you can use them as you wish in your project / they are equal).

When you are using `import` syntax in *bar.ts* you are trying to consume external module.

But *foo.ts* is not external module until you add `export` into root scope.

I'd recommend to stay with `import` and use external modules like this:

**Foo.ts**

```
export class Bar {
}
```

**Bar.ts**

```
import { Bar } from "./Foo"; // path needs to be relative here
// if referencing files are in same folder use ./ to force the path to be relative
```

There is no need to use `module`/`namespace` until you want to wrap classes into namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read some of the documentation.  A quick google gave me [this, which explains the different between namespace and module.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html/) Take a look at that and try to get a better view of exactly what it is that you need because I cannot exactly tell by your post because it seems syntax for modules would be `declare module "Foo" {...}` and based on what I'm seeing there it seems namespace may be what you want.  I'm not entirely sure but I feel like your answer is on that page.